# Why HTML/JavaScript widget is not showing in my blogspot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogspot

Since I enabled https redirect in my blog my HTML/JavaScript widget is not showing. but before that the same HTML/JavaScript code was worked and widget showed. I also searched about it but nothing found without HTTPS Redirect disabling. I disabled the HTTPS Redirect option. But nothing changed still HTML/JavaScript widget is not showing. what can I do now ??

[HTML code that worked before HTTPS Redirect enable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UORjQ.png)

[Not working same code after HTTPS enable (now disabled).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TQAf.png)

Please Help ..

Comment: Hard to tell without code.

Comment: Please provide more info unable to understand by snapshot. Add more snaps and code

Comment: Make sure that external files are correctly loaded via HTTPS, otherwise some browser will block the ressource and the page/widget wont work correct as some code is missing.

Comment: Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I solved this issue in Blogger.
It will happen if you allowed blog feed short in **Settings > Other > Site feed**

[image: Like this Screenshot 1]

To fix it please make sure your allowed blog feed is full in **Settings > Other > Site feed**.

[image: Like this Screenshot 2]